# Whats the advantage of importing bootstrap.scss to styles.scss over adding to styles block in .angular.cli.json?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

Whats the advantage of importing bootstrap.scss to styles.scss file over adding .angular.cli.json styles block.

which approach is good and why?

styles.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

vs

.angular-cli.json

```
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

I want to understand is there any benefits in build size ..etc. the styles required for page will load..so the bundle size will reduce etc..

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to custom Bootstrap (default padding, margin, colors, etc) then you could do it thanks to scss.

You could just override some values and you should be good to go.

If you import the css within angular-cli.json, you won't be able to do that (in a clean/proper) way. (but it's fine, maybe you don't need to!)

Now, if you don't want to customize Bootstrap, you should just put it in angular-cli.json with the css otherwise you'll be compiling all Bootstrap source code over and over which might be a waste of time if you don't need customization.

Comment: Is there any benefits in build size ?

Comment: No, except if use decide to use import and import bootstrap in many places which is not a good idea and might include bootstrap multiple times. That said, if you want to have a benefit in size, you might fork bootstrap for your own needs and within your fork remove the sub part you do not use from this file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap.scss and it might considerably help to decrease CSS total size

Answer (score 0):

Styles files should be for user custom styles. Lib styles better to import in angular-cli.json
It makes code more maintainable and easier to understand

Comment: Is there any benefits in build size ?

Comment: I don;t think so, since it is just different ways to import s

Comment: but in case of react I read it somewhere..it will download only whats style required for page or will download only what we are using..